# can we use jdk1.6 for developing opennms1.16

Tags: opennms

I have to use jdk1.6 for opennms 1.17. because jdk 1.6 is all ready used for some applications in my system and don't want to disturb that.

as of now I found that opennms 1.17 must require jdk1.8 or later.I am getting fatel error if have versions less then jdk1.8.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, you can't. The **OpenNMS** team stopped using **jdk 1.6** since version **1.14**. However, you can still developing **OpenNMS 1.12 or 1.13** base on jdk 1.6.

You can find more details here http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Upgrade_Guide:_1.12_to_1.14